# How to use OSGI to achieve zero down time?

Tags: osgi, apache-servicemix

I am thinking about using servicemix for my production server, I wonder if I use OSGI servlets  does that mean I can deploy a new version of my application without downtime? If not, is there a way to achieve zero-downtime server? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OSGi dynamic services might help you to upgrade your server without restarting it. This however indicates that your application is at the top of OSGi ladder. Dynamically acquiring the service is not enough. Application should preserve its state while achieving dynamism. Refer the OSGi maturity model by graham charters. [1]

In the real world zero downtime is achieved by replication/clustering. example setup is like, Two serviceMix servers , fronend by a load-balancer. When we are upgrading one server you point the load balancer to other vice versa. just an example.

[1] http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/09/mmm-osgi

Answer (score 1):

Zero downtime is impossible, no matter what you use. There's far too many external factors at play in the real world. OSGi helps mitigate downtime in upgrade scenarios by allowing different versions of a service to run concurrently, allowing connections to use the newer service, and then upon the last active connection's drop, the old servlet will be shut off.

Answer (score 1):

OSGi can reduce or even eliminate the planned downtime on a single server. It can be zero (or as close to zero as makes no difference) if you are able to deploy the new version before un-deploying the old version.

However the problem as hinted by other commenters is unplanned downtime: OSGi cannot save you from a hardware failure in a server.

For resilience you **must** have more than one server, e.g. a cluster. Once you have this, it really doesn't make much difference how long it takes to upgrade the software on one particular server (as long as it isn't *hours* or *days*...).

Answer (score 1):

Though you can deploy multiple versions of an OSGi bundle in the same container, this really doesn't help because your servlets would need to bind to different URLs to avoid port conflicts.  Then, clients would need to know to switch to this new URL.  This could be abstracted by updating routing configuration dynamically in an proxy server, etc.  Either way, it complicates deployment and your architecture is still limited in other ways (HA, etc).

Instead, a better option would be to use a cluster of Servicemix instances (and a load-balancer) on different machines.  Then do the standard stop/redeploy/start on each server to perform an upgrade.  This also addresses high availability and horizontal scalability needs, etc.